# Reverse an array upside down?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not talking about `array_flip()`, i want to reverse an array without a numerical/alphabetical basis, just *upside down*.

Example:

```
array('music','television','hollywood');
```

Will be:

```
array('hollywood','television','music');
```

Thanks!

Comment: You simply want to "reverse" the array. From reading your title, I nervously expected you to want to reverse an array of strings and make each string appear upside down (see: http://fliptext.org).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you'd want to use [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Answer (score 4):

how about [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)?

Answer (score 2):

Try [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-reverse.php).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're talking about, I think you want [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php); the term for what you want is just called "reversing".  I'm not sure I understand what you want (I, for one—and I think others too—tend to think of arrays as horizontal, so "upside-down" is a strange concept to apply to them, at least to me), though, so if this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I've always thought of them sort of like lists, so "upside down" made sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, especially if you use a *pretty* code editor to display arrays.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: I think of lists horizontally, too :-)

Comment: So you write your grocery lists on ticker tape? :P

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Hah!  No, I just program enough that "list" means apparently means "linked list" to me :-)  I've never thought of arrays that way.