# Reverse array values in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = array(2, 7, 44, 55);
```

I have to reverse values in that same array. Does someone knows how can I do that without using php built-in functions?

Comment: Why don't you want to use built-in functions? o0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse an array upside down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420037/reverse-an-array-upside-down)

Comment: It's a test for employment, I have to do it like that.

Comment: @emir89 made my day xD hahahaha

Comment: @bartek It's one of the basic questions, there is much more harder questions that I solved :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use built-in functions, try:

```
$a = array(2, 7, 44, 55);
$r = array();

for($i = count($a); $i>0; $i--) {
    $r[] = $a[$i-1];
}
$a = $r;

// checking...
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without PHP built-in functions.

```
$a = array(2, 7, 44, 55);
$temp = array();
for($i=count($a);$i>0;$i--){
  $temp[]=$a[$i-1];
}
$a = $temp;    
print_r($a);
```

Comment: What's the difference between your and my solution?

Comment: var_dump and print_r?